# How do I use Menu with Collapse as my TransitionComponent on Material-ui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, menu, transition

I'm having issues using the Collapse component as my TransitionComponent on Material-UI.

Not only does it not work, it also breaks the anchor.

Fade works fine, not sure where to look for answers.

[Link to codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/7jzzyrzwk0)

```js
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Menu, MenuItem, Collapse, Fade, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";

function App() {
  const [open, toggle] = useState(false);
  const ref = useRef(null);

  return (
    <>
      <div style={{ position: "absolute", top: "50%" }} ref={ref}>
        <Typography variant="h4" className="App" onClick={() => toggle(true)}>
          Click me!
        </Typography>
      </div>
      <Menu
        TransitionComponent={Collapse}
        anchorEl={ref.current}
        open={open}
        onClose={() => toggle(false)}
      >
        <MenuItem>Item do menu</MenuItem>
      </Menu>
      <Menu
        TransitionComponent={Fade}
        transitionDuration={800}
        anchorEl={ref.current}
        open={open}
        onClose={() => toggle(false)}
      >
        <MenuItem>Item do menu</MenuItem>
      </Menu>
    </>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known bug with the `Collapse` transition in combination with the `Popover` component (which is used by `Menu`): https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/11337

Comment: @Grokku If this issue is important to you, I recommend that you give it a thumbs-up/+1 in GitHub since the popularity of issues does have an impact on their prioritization.

Comment: Thanks, I will follow that advice. That issue is somewhat important to me. I tried looking for something related on my own without success. Thanks for your help. Cheers.